# Ненасытная страсть обладать (–) словно прожорливое брюхо Гаргантюа

Tags: пунктуация, тире, союзы

> Ненасытная страсть обладать (–) словно прожорливое брюхо Гаргантюа

Возможно ли обоснованно поставить тире перед сравнительным союзом в данном типе предложения?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перед *словно* (а также перед *как*, *будто*, *точно*, *вроде как*, *всё равно что* и т. п.) тире обычно не ставится. Но Розенталь и Лопатин допускают его постановку в некоторых случаях:

> Отступления от этого положения у писателей-классиков и у современных авторов связаны с прежними пунктуационными нормами или с желанием подчеркнуть оттенок сравнения, содержащийся в сказуемом: Твои речи — будто острый нож (Л.); Такая фраза — всё равно что большой шлем в ералаше (Т.); Эта девушка — как праздник! (Аж.); Срок войны — что жизни век (Тв.); ([Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92))
>
> При акцентировании сказуемого (обычно в стилистических целях) тире возможно: Этот одинокий и, может быть, совершенно случайный выстрел — словно сигнал (Фурм.); Во рту у него горько от табаку-самосаду, голова — как гиря (Шол.); Чернеющие прогалины — как черные острова в белом снежном море (Бун.); Млечный Путь — как большое общество (Б. Паст.); Луна в небе — как среднеазиатская дыня (Ток.). ([Лопатин](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=106#pp106))

Дополнение (под влиянием ответа  Jasmin).
Если в данном примере убрать тире, то трудно понять, где граница между группой подлежащего и группой сказуемого, другими словами, возникает двусмысленность: то ли страсть к обладанию подобна брюху Гаргантюа, то ли речь о том, чтобы "обладать словно прожорливое брюхо Гаргантюа".

Answer (score 1):

**Ненасытная страсть обладать — словно прожорливое брюхо Гаргантюа.**

В данном случае тире нужно поставить **в обязательном порядке**, чтобы обозначить **состав подлежащего и сказуемого**. Это связано с тем, что в группу подлежащего входит **инфинитив** в роли несогласованного определения.

**Пояснение**

**Постановка тире** между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым при отсутствии связки как раз и  связана с необходимостью **определить состав** подлежащего и сказуемого. При наличии между ними сравнительного союза, частицы НЕ и др. эта задача упрощается, поэтому тире в общем случае не ставится.

Однако обратим внимание на то, что **это правило касается тех случаев, когда главные члены выражены сущ. в И.п.** (см. Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92). Если хотя бы один из них выражен инфинитивом, то тире ставится: **Чай пить — не дрова рубить.**

Другой пример: **Ученого учить — только портить.**

Таким образом, **при наличии в предложении инфинитива** определить состав главных членов становится **сложнее**, этим и объясняется сохранение тире при наличии частиц и союзов.